# How to convert multiple lines into fixed column lengths

Tags: unix, awk, sed

To convert rows into tab-delimited, it's easy

`cat input.txt | tr "\n" " "`

But I have a long file with 84046468 lines. I wish to convert this into a file with 1910147 rows and 44 tab-delimited columns. The first column is a text string such as `chrXX_12345_+` and the other 43 columns are numerical strings. Is there a way to perform this transformation?

There are `NA`s present, so I guess `sed` and substituting "\n" for "\t" if the string preceding is a number doesn't work.

sample input.txt

```
chr10_1000103_+
0.932203
0.956522
1
0.972973
1
0.941176
1
0.923077
1
1
0.909091
0.9
1
0.916667
0.8
1
1
0.941176
0.904762
1
1
1
0.979592
0.93617
0.934783
1
0.941176
1
1
0.928571
NA
1
1
1
0.941176
1
0.875
0.972973
1
1
NA
0.823529
0.51366
chr10_1000104_-
0.952381
1
1
0.973684
```

sample output.txt

```
chr10_1000103_+   0.932203 (numbers all tab-delimited)
chr10_1000104_-   etc
(sorry alot of numbers to type manually)
```

Comment: Provide some sample input. You can give a try to `xargs`: for example, `seq 10 | xargs -n4` will join in blocks of 4 items per line. The same happens with `seq 10 | paste - - - -`.

Comment: `xargs` is awesome! Learnt something new today thanks! The output has a weird `^M` separator. Ok, I found the answer. [link](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/32001/what-is-m-and-how-do-i-get-rid-of-it) :)

Comment: Don't you think you could have demonstrated your problem with, say, 4 columns instead of 44 so you wouldn't have as much typing to do and we wouldn't have as much reading? The "answers" posted so far are ridiculously complex and I suspect it's because most people can't be bothered to read your question. If you post some sensible sample input and actual expected output I expect you will get the right answer which will almost certainly be a tiny one-line awk script.

Comment: Possible typo in question? It says "if the string preceding is a number", but shouldn't that be '*following* string' instead of 'string preceding'?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not the best solution, but should work:

```
line="nonempty"; while [ ! -z "$line" ]; do for i in $(seq 44); do read line; echo -n "$line "; done; echo; done < input.txt
```

If there is an empty line in the file, it will terminate. For a more permanent solution I'd try perl.

---

edit:

If you are concerned with efficiency, just use awk.

```
awk '{ printf "%s\t", $1 } NR%44==0{ print "" }' < input.txt
```

You may want to strip the trailing tab character with `| sed 's/\t$//'` or make the awk script more complicated.

Comment: Awesome. This works without the need to `sed -e 's/^M$//' < input.txt > output.txt`

Comment: It will also strip leading/trailing spaces from lines and remove backslashes and add trailing blank chars and be IMMENSELY inefficient.

Comment: The awk will leaving a trailing tab on the end of each line. What about `'{ printf "%s", $1 } NR%44==0{ print "" } else { printf "\t" }'` so that it prints each string following either by a tab or a newline (but not both)?

Comment: Yup, I mentioned that in my original post. I'd just use
`NR%44==0{print $1;next }  { printf "%s\t",$1 }`

Answer (score 1):

```
sed '
# use a delimiter
s/^/M/
:Next
# put a counter
s/^/i/
# test counter
/^\(i\)\{44\}/ !{
   $ !{
# not 44 line or end of file, add the next line
      N
# loop    
      b Next
      }
    }

# remove marker and counter
s/^i*M//
# replace new line by tab
s/\n/     /g' YourFile
```

some limite if more than 255 tab on sed (so 44 is ok)

Answer (score 1):

Here's the right approach using 4 columns instead of 44:

```
$ cat file
chr10_1000103_+
0.932203
0.956522
1
chr10_1000104_-
0.952381
1
1

$ awk '{printf "%s%s", $0, (NR%4?"\t":"\n")}' file
chr10_1000103_+ 0.932203        0.956522        1
chr10_1000104_- 0.952381        1       1
```

Just change 4 to 44 for your real input.

If you are seeing control-Ms in your output it's because they are present in your input so use dos2unix or similar to remove them before running the tool or with GNU awk you could just set `-v RS='\n\r'`.

When posting questions it's important to make it as clear, simple, and brief as possible so that as many people as possible will be interested in helping you.

BTW, `cat input.txt | tr "\n" " "` is a UUOC and should just be `tr "\n" " " < input.txt`

Answer (score 0):

This might work for you (GNU sed):

```
sed '/^chr/!{H;$!d};x;s/\n/\t/gp;d' file
```

If a line does not begin with `chr` append it to the hold space and then delete it unless it is the last. If the line does start `chr` or it is the last line, then swap to the hold space and replace all newlines by tabs and print out the result.

N.B. the start of the next line will be left untouched in the pattern space which becomes the new hold space.